# excel macro: Delete row with 1 or more blank cells and shift data up

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete row entries with at least 1 or more blank cells and shift the series up x # of partially filled rows. I also want to only delete the data in the row for a specified # of columns.

I've tried:

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()
With Worksheets("CSV_data")
    .UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End With
End Sub
```

However, I'm getting errors with overlapping values. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to loop through each row (backwards) and do condition statements (`IF` block or `Select Case`) against the columns to determine if a row or data in the rows should be deleted. If you still get stuck, then post before and after sample data and the looping code you have and we can probably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` range is Nothing, then you cannot do anything with it, thus you are getting an error when you try the `.Delete` operation. Thus, you may try to assign it to a range, resume in case of an error and check whether the range is nothing. Like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteBlankRows()

    Dim checkRange As Range

    With Worksheets("CSV_data")

        On Error Resume Next
        Set checkRange = .UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not checkRange Is Nothing Then
            checkRange.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd probably advise against using `.UsedRange` as this can be a little finicky sometimes

Comment: @Maldred - it is not a good idea to use it indeed. `On Error Resume Next` is also not a good idea.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this fully answers his question here, or maybe I'm just not understanding OP's question fully... As at first glance, it seems OP wants to delete a row IF AND ONLY IF the row has 1 or more blank cells; however "*I also want to only delete the data in the row for a specified # of columns*" is a little conflicting here...

Comment: @Maldred yes, I'm trying to delete a row if and only if the row has 1 or more blanks. I wanted to go further to say if we can get away with not deleting the entire row that would be best because I only want to apply this operation to a select number of columns. If that's impossible I can rearrange the workbook to conserve the columns in which I don't want data deleted.

Comment: @Jordan in that case, it might be best to use `.Cells.ClearContents` within a specified `Range()`. This could be done with a few loops and conditional `If` statements